# problem with grid (Div)

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have a problem with the grid i am working on. Basically i am creating a grid using divs. So as you can imagine, there is a container div which is filled with rows and cells. What i can seem to figure out is how to center the cells. For my container div, i have used auto left and right margin with a fixed width as shown below.

```
#container {
     margin: 0 auto;
     width:960px;
} 

#container .row { 
    height: 220px; 
    margin-bottom:20px; 
} 

#container .row .cell { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 20px 20px 20px; 
    height: 170px; 

}
```

That seems fine, but what i want is to have the div(s) in the container centered, so for instance, if i have just one cell(div) in the container div, it should be centered in the container div.

Comment: Why aren't you using tables? That's why they exist.

Comment: i know but using tables is not the best option when accessiblity is taken into consideration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of floating the "cells" make them into inline blocks, then they'll centre like text

```
#container {
     margin: 0 auto;
     width:960px;
     border: 14px solid #000;
} 

#container .row { 
    height: 220px; 
    margin-bottom:20px; 
    background: #cfc;
    text-align: center; /** add this **/
} 

#container .row .cell { 
    /*float: left;*/  /* remove this */
    display: inline-block; /* add this */
    margin: 0 20px 20px 20px; 
    height: 170px; 
    background: #dad;
}


/* IE7 and below needs the following rule to make inline-block work on block level element - disclaimer: this is a hack you can put this in a conditional comment for `lte IE 7` without the '!ie7' bit if you don't like hacks */
#container .row .cell { display: inline !ie7;}
```

Comment: +1, and here's the demo I literally just finished making: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/3yqUR/ The only other text from my answer in progress was this: "I'm assuming that you're just using badly named classes, and that it would actually be a mistake to use tables here because it would be *using tables for layout*."

Comment: +1 agree with your addition, but I think tables, rows and cells are here to haunt us forever even in describing layouts - I use them myself at times (when describing that is!) eeek :)

Comment: why didn't i think of that? Excellent, thanks...that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can not center that div because you are using float here.

if you float any div to left or right

then it can't move to center of parent div.

if  you want to create grid than you can also use span or any other inline element not block level element